# Jekyll Error - "serve" only works once

Tags: ruby, build, jekyll, serve

Started working on an update to my website. It was working fine the other day but now I get an error.

I generally type on CMD (i'm on Windows 10) "bundle exec Jekyll serve --watch" and the server goes. I can edit and save and its all reflected in browser upon refresh.

Now I can do this, but if I make one change to any file it works. Do another change and I get an error. I have to terminate and type again.

Below is the error:

```
D:\Tristen Grant\Documents\GitHub\portfolio>bundle exec jekyll serve --watch
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Configuration file: D:/Tristen Grant/Documents/GitHub/portfolio/_config.yml
    Source: D:/Tristen Grant/Documents/GitHub/portfolio
    Destination: D:/Tristen Grant/Documents/GitHub/portfolio/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
    Generating...
    done in 0.595 seconds.
Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'D:/Tristen Grant/Documents/GitHub/portfolio'
Configuration file: D:/Tristen Grant/Documents/GitHub/portfolio/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:3000//
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
    Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-09-06 16:16:28 ...done in 0.521498 seconds.
Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-09-06 16:16:30 ...error:
    Error: No such file or directory - git rev-parse HEAD
    Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.
[2016-09-06 16:19:35] ERROR Errno::ENOTSOCK: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
    C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

I'm using Ruby 2.1.5 64 bit version. RubyDevKit, Sass, Bourbon.

Any ideas how to fix this? I don't know much about Jekyll or ruby. Just starting out.

Comment: no idea if this will work but did you try the flag the error suggests `Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental`

Comment: Could be easier to debug if you provide your GitHub URL. Enabling incremental build won't fix this. The error message looks similar to this issue: https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/issues/57

Comment: `Error: No such file or directory - git rev-parse HEAD` seems to point at a problem with you git.

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error in CMD. You should have [github's desktop app](https://desktop.github.com/) installed; try running the same commands from the GitShell you get with that app.

For me that works, it saves me the trouble of installing git globally on Windows and setting it up.